# get response from cmd with visual basic

Tags: android, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008, vpn, file-transfer

I made an application in Visual Basic that opens cmd and transfer files to an Android receiver over VPN. it works fine but how do i get the response from cmd to check whether the transfer was succesful or not?

sample codes

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub btnSend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
    Shell("cmd.exe /k" + "adb push C:\Users\user\Desktop\Newfolder\1.png /sdcard/test")

End Sub

Private Sub btnConnect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnConnect.Click
    Shell("adb connect " + TextBox1.Text)
    btnSend.Enabled = True
    btnConnect.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: @SemicolonsandDuctTape i edited my post can u help me with my new question?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are wanting to get the return code or std output of the adb commands. Either way you are going to need to start your own process instead of using the Shell command because:

*A process can return an exit code when it terminates. However, you cannot use Shell to retrieve this exit code, because Shell returns zero if it waits for termination, and also because the process runs in a different object from Shell.* From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe736fyk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

the link will show you how to set up a processes that returns an exit code. The relevant code is

```
Dim procID As Integer
Dim newProc As Diagnostics.Process
newProc = Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\WINDOWS\NOTEPAD.EXE")
procID = newProc.Id
newProc.WaitForExit()
Dim procEC As Integer = -1
If newProc.HasExited Then
    procEC = newProc.ExitCode
End If
MsgBox("Process with ID " & CStr(ProcID) & _
    " terminated with exit code " & CStr(procEC))
```

if you are wanting not the return code, but the standard output from the program, then according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-4
you can do that via this code snippet:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Diagnostics

Class IORedirExample
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim args() As String = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
        If args.Length > 1
            ' This is the code for the spawned process'

            Console.WriteLine("Hello from the redirected process!")
        Else 
            ' This is the code for the base process '

            Dim myProcess As New Process()
            ' Start a new instance of this program but specify the spawned version. '

            Dim myProcessStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo(args(0), "spawn")
            myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
            myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
            myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo
            myProcess.Start()
            Dim myStreamReader As StreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput
            ' Read the standard output of the spawned process. '
            Dim myString As String = myStreamReader.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine(myString)

            myProcess.WaitForExit()
            myProcess.Close()
        End If 
    End Sub 
End Class
```

when you are trying this out yourself, remember that you must include the

```
myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
```

line as well.